# Can't access my hdd

Tags: hard-drive

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04, first time trying out Ubuntu.

Its dual install, I have windows 8 on my computer also.

The problem is I got four hdd, and I see them, but when I try to click on them. Nothing happens.

Error mounting, The disk contains an unclean file system, metadata kept in windows cache.

I’ve googled my ass off and tried out everything, but it never seems to be addressing exactly my problem. So I ask you, how can I fix this :)

Comment: I think you should list what *exactly* you mean by the "everything" you have tried. ;)

Comment: The problem could be that your windows 8 is hibernating instead of being shut down entirely. That way the windows partitions are 'locked' and Ubuntu can not mount them.

Answer (score 3):

> When Windows 8 is restarted using its fast restarting feature, part of
>   the metadata of all mounted partitions are restored to the state they
>   were at the previous closing down. As a consequence, changes made on
>   Linux may be lost. This can happen on any partition of an internal
>   disk when leaving Windows 8 by selecting Shut down or Hibernate.
>   Leaving Windows 8 by selecting Restart is apparently safe.
>
> To avoid any loss of data, be sure the fast restarting of Windows 8 is
>   disabled. This can be achieved by issuing as an administrator the
>   [command](http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/no-fast-restart.html) :
>
> or follow this step :
>
> Settings --> control panel --> system security --> administrative
>   tools --> system configuration --> tools --> command prompt and launch
>   it and type this :
>
> ```
> powercfg /h off
> ```
>
> You can check the current settings on :
>
> Control Panel --> Hardware and Sound --> Power Options --> System
>   Setting --> Choose what the power buttons do
>
> The box `Turn on fast startup` should either be disabled or missing.

<sup>Source:[Here](http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html#windows8)</sup>